# How to create a script that creates a full database schema in the proper order?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to script a whole SQL Server database (tables, views, functions, procedures, users).

I tried the "generate scripts" function of management studio, but it creates the objects in the bad order, I would like that the creation order makes sense, for example this creation order makes sense for a  minimalistic 4 tables only database:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINES
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIERS
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
CREATE TABLE USERS
```

Is there are least a way to list all the database objects in dependency order (from the least dependent to the most dependent)?

What I am trying to achieve is to make a copy of a database on the same server instance without using a backup file.

Thanks

Comment: >>>to make a copy of a database<<< So you want only schema or schema + data?

Comment: You can also use SSIS to copy a database (with or without data), or SSDT (SQL Server project) to export the schema and create a dacpac file. You can export the data-tier application file (dacpac) using SSMS and re-deploy it using command line or SSMS. In SSDT you can do a schema compare and perform a sync. There are 3rd party tools too.

This question in my opinion is a bit broad for SO, but might make sense on [dba.se].

Comment: @sepupic i want schema and data but i'd like to write the queries for data after a rock solid script for schema has been  created.

Comment: @Pred I will ook into SSIS thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use sp_detach_db 'DatabaseName', then copy and paste the files (data and log files mdf and ldf)and then reattach it.

The copied files can then be used to reattach it with another name:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyAdventureWorks   
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database

Comment: I do not want to use backup or mdf ldf filestream files. I am looking for a script only way to replciate tabular data.